# How to explain this Objective C method declaration "- method:parameter;"

Tags: objective-c, syntax, methods

Declaring, implementing and using method like this:

Test.h:

```
- method:parameter;
```

Test.m:

```
- method:parameter{
    return nil;
}
```

Using:

```
[test method:anObject];
```

There is no return-type and parameter-type, but it works without any warning or error. 
Can somebody explain it?

Comment: The return type is void the return value is nil !

Comment: @ViTo Brothers Apoyan, actually no, it's `id` if it's unspecified.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the [Objective-C Programming Language document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html) states:

> If a return or parameter type isn’t explicitly declared, it’s assumed to be the default type for methods and messages — an `id`.

So:

```
- method:parameter;
```

effectively means:

```
- (id)method:(id)parameter;
```

and, correspondingly:

```
- method:parameter{
    return nil;
}
```

effectively means:

```
- (id)method:(id)parameter{
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF122):

> If a return or parameter type isn’t
>   explicitly declared, it’s assumed to
>   be the default type for methods and
>   messages—an `id`.

Answer (score 3):

Default type in Obj-C is `id`. So here the both the return and parameter is `id`.